# Intellij 2021.3.2, JavaFX Maven project not resolving dependencies correctly

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, javafx, pom.xml

I added a [library](https://github.com/web3j/web3j) to my JavaFX projects following these steps:

1. File --> Project Structure --> Project Settings --> Libraries --> + --> Maven
2. Insert the Maven coordinates and checked the "Download to projectPath/libs"
3. In pom.xml added the correct dependecy declaration
4. In module-info.java added the 'requires module'

Importing the library to my class seems to work, but after calling a method from the library, it results in a

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.web3j.utils.Numeric
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:606)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:168)
```

Now, i initially thought was a library problem, but reproducing the **same steps** in a normal Maven project (and trying to run the same exact code snippet) works perfectly.

Any ideas why this could happen? Am i doing something wrong in importing the library?

**HELLOAPPLICATION.JAVA**

```
public class HelloApplication extends Application {
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(HelloApplication.class.getResource("hello-view.fxml"));
    Scene scene = new Scene(fxmlLoader.load() , 320 , 240);
    stage.setTitle("Hello!");
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
    Web3j web3j = Web3j.build(new HttpService("http://127.0.0.1:8545"));
    web3j.ethGetBlockByNumber(DefaultBlockParameter.valueOf(new BigInteger("14000000")), true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch();
}
```

}

Edit:

**POM.XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>demo</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>demo</name>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <junit.version>5.8.1</junit.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
        <version>17.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
        <version>17.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.web3j</groupId>
        <artifactId>web3j-evm</artifactId>
        <version>4.9.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>17</source>
                <target>17</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.8</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <!-- Default configuration for running with: mvn clean javafx:run -->
                    <id>default-cli</id>
                    <configuration>
                        <mainClass>com.example.demo/com.example.demo.HelloApplication</mainClass>
                        <launcher>app</launcher>
                        <jlinkZipName>app</jlinkZipName>
                        <jlinkImageName>app</jlinkImageName>
                        <noManPages>true</noManPages>
                        <stripDebug>true</stripDebug>
                        <noHeaderFiles>true</noHeaderFiles>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**MODULE-INFO.JAVA**

```
module com.example.demo {
requires javafx.controls;
requires javafx.fxml;
requires core;
opens com.example.demo to javafx.fxml;
exports com.example.demo;}
```

Comment: Please try to build your project first on plain command line with Maven....

Comment: @khmarbaise do you mean mvn verify?

Comment: Yes for example or a `mvn package` should also work...

Comment: Yes, it works. I didn't set any 'distributionManagement' in my pom.xml, so mvn deploy doesn't work; I followed to the 'Maven build lifecycle', and all the others command returns 'Build succes'.

Comment: So this means the configuration in your pom file is correct. Now you should import the project into IDEA IntelliJ... before that delete `.idea` directory...

Comment: Also the .iml, right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243064/discussion-between-mattia-monari-and-khmarbaise).

Comment: You shouldn't change the project structure if you configure your project via pom.xml. These changes getting overwritten.

Comment: Provide a [mcve] with pom.xml and enough Java code to replicate the issue via copy and paste.

Comment: @jewelsea thanks for pointing it out. I just did it.

Comment: @ValerijDobler What do you mean by 'changing project structure'?

Comment: I think it's a bad idea to add the dependent JARs to your project path.  Pull them down to your local .m2.  IntelliJ will do this properly if you let it.  I don't use module-info.  It feels like you're doing too much.

Comment: Thanks @duffymo, i'll try. About the module-info.java, i'm trying to understand if that is necessary or not. If i remove it, JavaFX won't work, and if i don't add the 'requires core' i can't import the lib in the HelloApplication. Is there a workaround ?

Comment: I don't understand "can't import the lib".  I'll see if I can make your stuff work locally for me.

Comment: I mean, if i don't add the 'requires core' in the module-info.java, trying to 'import org.web3j;' will throw an error since 'package org.web3j does not exists'. Appreciate your help.

Comment: Tried your stuff locally.  I can't resolve all the dependencies for web3jm-evm from Maven Central.  It's pulling in a bunch of JARs from org.hyperledger.besu that aren't in Maven Central.  Everything else is fine.  All I did was add your main class and the pom.xml.  No module-info or fancy stuff.  Let IntelliJ do it.  It knows how.

Comment: Did you used a normal project or a JavaFX one?

Comment: @jewelsea Thanks for the detailed answer; I think I've enough to work on. I'm probably gonna start using a JDK which includes JavaFX modules (seems more appropiate to my capabilities) and let you know. Appreciate the help.

Comment: That will mean an older JDK.  They have removed it from the newer ones.  I think there's value in figuring out how to add JavaFX as a dependency.  That way you can take advantage of JDK 17 and beyond.

Comment: They removed JavaFX from JDK 11 and newer.  You want to figure out how to do it with JDK 11 and 17.  No one should be using JDK 8 anymore.

Comment: @duffymo JavaFX is included in some recent JDK distributions, for instance [BellSoft Liberica Full JDK 17 and Full JRE 17](https://bell-sw.com/pages/downloads/#/java-17-lts%20/%20current), [Azul Zulu JDK FX 17](https://www.azul.com/downloads/?version=java-17-lts&os=windows&architecture=x86-64-bit&package=jdk-fx). They are alternatives to either pulling the [JavaFX modules from the maven repository](https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:org.openjfx) or [manually downloading the modules and SDK from Gluon](https://gluonhq.com/products/javafx/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the comments, you seem to be using some less common libraries. Sometimes, those kinds of libraries are not updated to be compatible with the [Java Platform Module System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform_Module_System). I think it is probably safe to assume that unless you know otherwise.

**Defining a non-modular project**

The easiest way to deal with such dependencies is to make your project non-modular: delete the `module-info.java`.

But JavaFX itself is only supported as modules. So, even though your project and its dependencies are non-modular, you should still place the JavaFX libraries on the module path.

**Using a JDK which includes JavaFX**

To accomplish such a setup (non-modular application using JavaFX modules), the easiest way is to rely on a JDK or JRE that includes JavaFX modules, for example, the [Zulu **JDK FX**](https://www.azul.com/downloads/?version=java-17-lts&os=windows&architecture=x86-64-bit&package=jdk-fx) distribution or the [Liberica **Full JDK**](https://bell-sw.com/pages/downloads/#/java-17-lts%20/%20current) distribution. *It is important to use the correct distribution as the base JDK distributions for Zulu and Liberica do not include JavaFX.*

**Using a base JDK which does not include JavaFX**

With a bit more work, you can use OpenJDK. You can do this by sourcing the JavaFX modules from either the [maven repository with a build tool](https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:org.openjfx), or a [manual download of the modules and SDK from Gluon](https://gluonhq.com/products/javafx/).  In all your build and execution steps, you need to ensure that all of those modules are on the module path and declared to the module system via either VM arguments or a `module-info.java`.

*Building with Maven*

For a Maven build, you need to add each module to the module path individually, as they are all in separate directories in the local `.m2` repository (modern Maven systems and some IDEs, such as Idea, will do that automatically, other IDEs such as VSCode may not).

*Building with the SDK*

Alternately, don't add dependencies on the JavaFX modules via Maven. Instead, download the JavaFX SDK and add the JavaFX modules there via VM arguments `--module-path` and `--add-modules`. This process for adding JavaFX modules to OpenJDK is documented in the [getting started documentation at openjfx.io](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/).

**A note on openjfx.io Maven archetypes**

Note that the openjfx.io getting started documentation around this mentions maven archetypes.  My advice is not to use those as they are really difficult to work with if you try to use them from IDEs. Instead, use the Idea [new JavaFX project wizard](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/javafx.html), either keeping the module-info.java it generates for a modular project or removing it and manually specifying JavaFX module VM arguments for a non-modular project.

**Issues with your project build**

In terms of your actual project, I encountered the same error that duffymo pointed out in the comments:

> I can't resolve all the dependencies for web3jm-evm from Maven Central. It's pulling in a bunch of JARs from org.hyperledger.besu that aren't in Maven Central.

So I was unable to build or test it.